# Java OOP using Translate Transition and JavaFX

Tags: oop, javafx, transition, translate

The Translate Transition does not output. It uses a method in the main class. I believe it is not working because it is used as an object. There has to be a different code to implement. It uses a method in a main and then puts it into a tester. However, I do not know how to use it because it uses a constructor/object as well. Then, the object turns and changes into a node which I changed it. `I do not know how the Translate Transition method is attached to the object and displays it into the javafx console.` Please help solve the problem for positive feedback as it shows.

```
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class AnxiousShapes {

    private Shape shape;
    private double delay ;
    private int howFarToMoveX;
    private int howFarToMoveY;

    public AnxiousShapes(int type, int x, int y, int size, double delay, Color color, int hftmX, int hftmY) {
        if (type == 0) {shape = new Circle(x, y, size, color);}
        //these are the only lines you can change
        //in this main class
        //else if (type == 1){shape = new Rectangle(x,y,color);}
        //else if (type == 2){shape = new Polygon();} 
        //else if (type == 3) {shape = new Circle(x, y, size, color);}
        //else { System.out.println("Error in type");shape = new  
        //Circle(???????);}
        this.delay = delay;
        this.howFarToMoveX = hftmX;
        this.howFarToMoveY = hftmY;
    }

    // getter and setters

    public TranslateTransition calculateTt() {
        TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(this.delay), this.shape); 
        tt.setToX(this.shape.getLayoutX() + howFarToMoveX);
        tt.setToY(shape.getLayoutY() + howFarToMoveY);  
        // Let the animation run forever -- if the shape
        // tries to move "off-screen" it will return to the beginning
        tt.setCycleCount(TranslateTransition.INDEFINITE);
        return tt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AnxiousShape [shape=" + shape + ", delay=" + delay + ", howFarToMoveX=" + howFarToMoveX
                + ", howFarToMoveY=" + howFarToMoveY + "]";
    }
}


import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;

import java.util.Random;

public class AnxiousShapesTester extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // adding the new things
        Group root = new Group();

        stage.setTitle("Welcome to JavaFX!");

        // create the shape circle 
        AnxiousShapes circle1 = new AnxiousShapes(0, 200, 200, 50, 15, 
        Color.GREEN, 10 ,35);
        root.getChildren().add(circle1.getShape());

//      this does not work
//      TranslateTransition trans = circle1.calculateTt();
//      trans.setNode(root);
//      trans.play();
//      and I tried this and I already have the movement in constructor for 
//      delay and x and y but TranslateTransition 
//      asks for duration.millis(500)
        TranslateTransition tt = new 
        TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(500), root);
        tt.play();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600, Color.WHITE);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, you say, "this does not work." The problem is `trans.setNode(root)`, which attempts to make `root` "The target node of this [`TranslateTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html#setNode-javafx.scene.Node-)." Your implementation of `calculateTt()` already specifies `this.shape` as the target node. Instead, add a suitable accessor to `AnxiousShapes` and use the transition as constructed; the following changes are illustrated below:

```
public Shape getShape() { return this.shape; }
…
AnxiousShapes circle1 = new AnxiousShapes(0, 100, 100, 100, 3, Color.GREEN, 400, 400);
root.getChildren().add(circle1.getShape());
TranslateTransition trans = circle1.calculateTt();
trans.play();
```

[image]