# Accessing elements inside a GraphicsContext in JavaFX canvas

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I'm implementing a simple hockey game following an MVC pattern. I'm having trouble refreshing the player's position, which I have created inside a canvas using the `GraphicsContext.drawImage()` method. I'm inside an `AnimationTimer` anonymous class, inside the `handle` method.

The positions and boundaries are all reflected to the backend,so I don't really need to do any particular logic here, I just want to refresh the player's position on every frame, based on its position calculated inside the model, but I can't access the image I've drawn before in any way. Here's the code:

```
DefaultController controller;

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    
    controller = new DefaultController(800, 400);
    
    double playerX = controller.getField().getPlayer().getX();
    double playerY = controller.getField().getPlayer().getY();
    
    double enemyX = controller.getField().getEnemy().getX();
    double enemyY = controller.getField().getEnemy().getY();

    context.drawImage(new Image("player.png"),playerX, playerY);
    context.drawImage(new Image("enemy.png"),enemyX, enemyY);

    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            pane.getScene().addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (key) -> {
                if (key.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                    controller.getField().getPlayer().setLocation(playerX,playerY-0.1)

                    // how do I update the player image position inside the canvas?
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: For more help post [mre] please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are following a completely wrong approach. You cannot update anything in a Canvas once it is drawn. You can just erase it and redraw it again. For what you are trying to do the scene graph is much better suited.

Comment: Examples of the approach suggested in this answer:  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55662601/3992939), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26477294/3992939)

Answer (score 2):

The following is an [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating how to move an image on a canvas using the UP key:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static final int SIZE = 200;
    private static final String FISH_IMAGE = "https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/03/28/14104_animal_256x256.png";
    private Image image;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private final double xPos = 250;
    private double yPos = 150;
    private static final double MOVE = 0.8;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        image = new Image(FISH_IMAGE,SIZE,SIZE,false,false);
        canvas = new Canvas(SIZE*3, SIZE*3);
        draw();
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(canvas));
        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (key) -> animate(key));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                //to avoid multiple handlers do not add handler here
                draw();
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
    
    private void animate(KeyEvent key){
          if(key.getCode()== KeyCode.UP) {
            yPos -= MOVE;
          }
          //todo add down, left , right 
         //for low rate animation, like response to key-press, invoke draw() here instead of using AnimationTimer 
    }

    private void draw(){
         GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
         gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());//clear previous
         gc.drawImage(image, xPos, yPos);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: How much energy do you want to waste that way instead of just doing it right? You are constantly redrawing the canvas whether it is necessary or not at 60 Hz instead of just adding an ImageView to a Pane and shifting it arround corresponding to the key which was hit. On a mobile device you would just drain the batteries in record time.

Comment: @mipa Thank you for your comment. I agree that in most cases manipulating objects on the graph scene would be better (there are many examples available such as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55662601/3992939), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26477294/3992939) ). However, the question (and my answer) is about manipulating objects on a canvas. Not about what is the best solution for this specific scenario.

Comment: According to my life experience it is often better to tell people that they are on the wrong track instead of trying to provide them with an inferior solution based on the wrong path which they have chosen for whatever reason.